# How to load geojson file in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, highcharts, geojson

I have been adding the following files in my cshtml page.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js" )"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/balochistan.geojson"></script>
```

And the code for higmaps is present on the same page with script tag. Everything is working fine but hte map is not displaying and giving error for geojson file not being loaded.

```
http://localhost:9090/Content/js/balochistan.geojson net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Can anyone please helpthat how a geojson file can be loaded properly and how to give static path to it correctly?

Comment: are you sure the file is existing on that path that is genertaed?

Comment: yesit is present on this path. but i think the problem is with the extension of this file. i have saved it as balochistan.geojson. would it be right or i have to save it as balochistan.geojson.json?

Comment: browse the path in browser window if it opens to verify

Comment: no its not opening.HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Comment: HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Comment: it's not allowing the extension, either you need to allow the extension

Comment: i have done this in the Web.config   <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".geojson" mimeType="application/geojson" />
  </staticContent>

Comment: now it is showing the following error: highcharts.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: a[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a constructor
    at n.fn.init.G.jQuery.G.jQuery.fn.highcharts (highcharts.js:33)
    at brace:945

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189043/discussion-between-ehsan-sajjad-and-sadia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved:**
The problem resolved by doing few steps like:
adding script tags in proper order. 
secondly highmaps.js and highcharts.js file conflict with each other when used on the same page.
In order to resolve this issue you have to add

```
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

script tag in addition to highcharts.js and also replace the highmaps.js with:

```
 <script src="//code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
```

like this:

```
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
```

This resolved my problem and  map is showing now.

Answer (score 0):

the file ends with `.geojson` can not be loaded like that - as script - because is a **json** file

Add this file is a set of **json data** - you need to loaded them on `highcharts` either with ajax load, either add them as variable at the beginning and connected to the chart.

Comment: can you please elaborate it further

Comment: @Sadia here is an example for geojson : https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/geojson/

Comment: @Sadia in the above example focus on this line -> `$.getJSON('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/germany.geo.json',`

Comment: @Sadia This is where the json are loaded as data and place them on the chart - you can not just include the data file and wait from the script to find them and use them.